# php script does not run when called from bash script on MAC OS X

Tags: php, bash, macos

Following is a bash script `run.command` that I am trying to use to call a PHP script

```
  #!/bin/bash
  #!/usr/bin/php
  # Main script 

php -f generateTest.php
```

Why does this not run when I "double click" the bash script ? It runs on calling from the `terminal` on OS X

I get the error message

```
asehgal-MacBook-Pro:~ asehgal$ /Users/asehgal/projects/configtest/run.command ; exit;
Could not open input file: generateTest.php
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

I have used `chmod +x` to make it executable.

Comment: Is `generateTest.php` in the same place as `run.command`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the absolute path to your generateTest.php file and it should work, it's not working now because it's trying to find generateTest.php in your current working directory (where you are running run.command from)

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/php
# Main script 

php -f /Users/asehgal/projects/configtest/generateTest.php
```

Comment: actually, i was just double clicking it and I forgot that on double clicking, a new terminal window opens that defaults to the home directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd -- "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")"
```

This needs to be there after the shebang line. Thats because when the terminal opens to run a bash script, it defaults to the current users home directory. Hence, we need to change the path to the folder out of which we expect to run out of.